# Acceder a clave de hashmap que contiene claves duplicadas

Tags: java, hashmap

Me ha surgido el siguiente problema:

habia creado un hashmap que contenía clave,objeto y lo rellenaba con datos devueltos de una query:

- **Objeto:**

  ```
      public class Registro {

      int posIni;
      int posFin;

         public Registro(Integer attr1, Integer attr2) {
         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

             posIni = attr1;
             posFin = attr2;
         }    
      }
  ```
- **Creación del hashmap:**

  ```
    Map<String, Object> listaEtiquetas = new HashMap<String, Object>();

      while(rs.next()) {

          POS_INI_ETI = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(2));     
          POS_INI = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(3));     
          POS_FIN = Integer.valueOf(rs.getString(4)); 
          ETIQUETA = rs.getString(1); 

          Registro objPrueba1 = new Registro(POS_INI, POS_FIN);

          listaEtiquetas.put(ETIQUETA, objPrueba1);

      }
  ```
- **Objetivo:**

El objetivo de crear el hashmap es recorrer unos ficheros muy grandes que hay que leer linea a linea y comprobar si los 4 primeros numeros coinciden con alguna de las claves, y en ese caso, acceder a su objeto y con la posicion inicial y final ir a la línea y en ese tramo sustituirlo por XXX:

```
    while((linea = reader.readLine()) != null){

            String rulo = "";

            //Recoge donde se debe encontrar la etiqueta guiandose por las posiciones inicial y final de base de datos de dicho país y servicio
            String etiqueta = linea.substring(POS_INI_ETI-1,(POS_INI_ETI + SIZE_ETI)-1);


            //En el caso de existir esa etiqueta como clave en el hashmap, accede y copia de la línea caracter a caracte para que al llegar a las posiciones donde se deben poner XXX, sustituir las letras por X
            //En el caso de no existir en el hashmap, copia directamente la línea completa
            if (listaEtiquetas.containsKey(etiqueta)) {

                //Recuperamos el objeto del hashmap correspondiente a la etiqueta que ha encontrado.
                Registro response2 = (Registro) listaEtiquetas.get(etiqueta);

                //creamos la variable u para recorrer caracter a caracter
                char u;

                for (int i = 0;i< linea.length();i++) {

                    if( i < (response2.posIni-1) || i>= (response2.posFin)) {

                        u = linea.charAt(i);
                        rulo += u;

                    } else {

                        rulo += 'X';
                    }
                }
            } else rulo = linea; 

            pw.println(rulo);
            System.out.println(rulo);
        }
```

-**Problema:**

Todo funciona correctamente, pero el problema viene cuando comprobamos que pueden existir dos claves con diferntes posiciones inio y fin.

¿se os ocurre una solución para preguntar por la clave y asi solo recorrer una vez el fichero?

Comment: En lugar de guardar un objecto Map<String, Object> guarda una lista <String, List<Object>> agregarías un for extra para ejecutar la n cantidad de elementos en la lista y ejecutar las posiciones de cada uno.

Comment: pero asi no se crearia una lista de objetos por cada clave? eso haria el proceso mas lento o tendria algun contra en cuanto a rendimiento?

Comment: No debería ser mucho pero toda lógica extra agregaría mas tiempo, ademas es la única forma de utilizar Map con keys repetidas, luego esta org.apache.commons commons-collections4 tiene una clase MultiMap pero de igual forma no creo que sea mas eficiente que hacerlo como te lo he planteado y de igual forma te retorna una lista de valores cuando realizas el get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que una sola clave de ese hashmap pueda tener varios registros. La solucion seria modificar ese hashmap  a hasmap >.

Como puntualización  si tienes una clase Registro porque creas un mapa de Object???

La creación del mapa quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
Map<String, List<Registro>> listaEtiquetas = new HashMap<String, List<Registro>>();
```

Comment: ok gracias! como puedo introducir los Registros en esa lista del hasmap¿? creo previamente la lista no? es que me esta dando errores

Comment: Exacto ,cuando crees el mapa con sus claves, tendrás que crear la lista para cada uno. A continuación haces un get (Clave) y obtendras un objeto lista y solo necesitaras un add(Registro).

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: Realmente no es necesario crear la lista siempre, puedes hacerlo solo cuando vallas a añadir el primer registro , mientras tanto con get(Clave) recibiras una lista NULA